# Multiple integers in one table MySql PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating an instant messaging website using PHP and MySQL.  I am very new to both of these languages.  I have a problem: When sending a message, it is 'received' and 'viewable' by  users with the same 'user_id' as that on the database.

So, if a user with ID 1 begins a conversation with a user with ID 2, 1 and 2 should be on the database.

How do I allow more than one number to be in a single field.  Please explain.

Whilst you might think that I could just make two fields (user_id_sent and user_id_sent_to), that is not possible since you can begin a conversation with any number of people.

Please help me to find out how to do this in PHPMyAdmin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you need is an extra table.

Comment: And what would the columns be?

Comment: I don't have much experience with chats, there is a number of ways to this. You'd probably need conversations table : conversation_id, title, started_by (user_id), comments table : comment_id, conversation_id, comment_text, user_id. You could work out what users are particapating in the conversation from the comments, or you could create an extra table (conversers) : convesation_id, user_id

Comment: I've somehow fixed it, but I really don't know how, so I can't share it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a mapping table between the message and the participants.
You would need three tables, one for the users, one for the messages and one that has only two columns (user-id and message-id). In this table there is an entry for every user that should have acess to the specified message.